# Syncing application with email without storing email passwords

Tags: security, email, web-applications

I'm working on a web-based application, and looking to integrate each user's e-mail (gmail, yahoo, etc.) into it. I'd like to do an automatic sync (side detail: selective to specific e-mail addresses) of inbox and sent messages, i.e. any messages sent through the application will appear in the user's e-mail, and vice versa; any messages received in the application will appear in the e-mail, and vice versa.

My question: I realize this will probably involve IMAP. Is there a way to go about this without storing the user's e-mail passwords? I'm open to any language, infrastructure, etc.

If there's really no way around storing the passwords, would MD5 be sufficient? Any other thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: short answer is no, you have to store the passwords. my question would be, why write this? gmail, yahoo, etc all provide this functionality in their own web interfaces..

Comment: they do. but, this application would pull selective emails and display it in a more relevant way. there is a purpose behind it, just difficult to explain the entire scope in a few sentences...

Comment: StackOverflow authenticates to Google Account using OpenID. Is that an option?

Comment: @mellamokb I think OP wants the private inbox on his site to automatically sync with the users gmail inbox, so they can view messages from his site in gmail.

Comment: yes, I did consider it - I can see it working for Gmail accounts. I guess my question is if there's anything similar for Yahoo, AOL, Hotmail, etc.?

Comment: @jzworkman, you're right - I wouldn't be able to accomplish this with OpenID?

Comment: OpenId allows you to log in with another accounts credentials but I dont believe you can access any of the information(such as email inbox) as that would be a huge security hole.  Many sites use OpenId to log in and create accounts with but they only receive a log on auth token, they dont have the full privileges of gmail.

Comment: aha, thanks for clarifying. it wouldn't work then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would need to find an OAuth-based API for accessing the email provider. this would allow the user to authenticate themself, provide you with an access token for later use.

I believe you can do this with [Gmail](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/oauth_overview), [Yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/mailapplications/auth.html) (see links)

Comment: I was thinking of OAuth but wasn't sure if it would be appropriate/work in this case. I'll check out the links - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A situation where this might arise is a private messaging system on a forum. A user might want PMs forwarded to their main email so that they don't have to remember to check the inbox on your site as well as their main email. Then when users reply to those messages, you want the reply to go as a PM to another forum user.

Forwarding PMs as emails is trivial. In order to allow replies, you need to have the email server on your site parse out some information in the email that indicates which user it should be forwarded to as a PM.

If you really want to allow a user to access their entire GMail inbox from within the interface on your site, rather than just messages that went through your site anyway, then you are facing a much larger task.

Comment: Thanks for this - I can see forwarding possibly working for incoming messages. But I'd still want to get messages sent through the application to appear in a user's email - in the sent-mail folder.